# How to add new systemcall in Linux 3.2.x?

Tags: linux, debian, kernel

I'm new to Linux, and I want to compile my kernel for Debian-amd64 with a new system call. The only tutorial I could find online was for a i386 or x86 system. I followed their instructions but at the end my new system call returned -1.

```
#define _CS2456_TEST_ 349    
printf ("\n%d\n",  syscall(_CS2456_TEST_ , 2456)) ;
```

My current kernel is 3.2.63.

How can I add a new system call into my kernel for AMD64? Either a description of the details or a good tutorial or guide would be helpful.

Comment: Can you print the value of `errno` after you call `syscall`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is pretty easy, there is a quick and small tutorial at https://arvindsraj.wordpress.com/2012/10/05/adding-hello-world-system-call-to-linux/